# NIB File Doesn't Display at Runtime

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, xib, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am pulling my hair out on this one.  I have a NavigationController with two levels of TableViews.  Each TableView is in its own NIB file.  The first level simply displays a list.  Upon selecting a cell, it takes the user to a second level TableView with a more detailed list.  It is on this second level TableView that I want to display a search bar (actually I am using a SearchDisplayController as well).  I have added it to the TableView because I want the SearchBar to scroll with the table.

Below, I am displaying two screenshots.  The first is the second level tableview in InterfaceBuidler.  The second is the second level tableview at runtime.  For some reason, the SearchBar doesn't display at runtime.

I have tried creating a completely new project from scratch and the same things happens.  I don't understand why the SearchBar doesn't display on a NIB pushed on the NavigationController.

Before you ask, if I put the SearchBar on the first level TableView, it shows up just fine.  Yes, I am adding it to the TableView itself, so it is a part of the view that should be displayed.

Help!  What am I doing wrong?

[image: XIB File]

This is what actually displays after the XIB is pushed...

[image: SearchBar Doesn't Display?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to have to answer my own question.  I thought about deleting it, but perhaps this could help someone else.  I really pulled my hair out on this one.  It wasn't because of anything I was doing wrong so much as a fundamental misunderstanding of how iPhone development works.

In a nutshell, the problem was with this line of code, which instantiated the TableViewController:

```
self.downloadDetailViewController = [[DownloadDetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

When you use XCode to create a new class, you can use the following:

"Add -> New File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> UIViewController subclass -> UITableViewController
subclass AND With XIB for user interface"

The problem is that the NIB has absolutely nothing to do with the UITableViewController until you tell your code to use it.  To me, this seems like a bug in XCode or at the very least something that is counterintuitive.  When the development environment creates all three files together, it would only make sense that they would work together, but they don't.

Instead, the solution is to modify the line of code as follows:

```
self.downloadDetailViewController = [[DownloadDetailTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondaryView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Hopefully this can help someone else...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are adding the searchbar to the tableView, so it is not displaying.

Try to add that searchBar with out adding to the table view, that means move the table view some what down and add the search bar to the view(not the tableview).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really accomplish what I'm after.  I want the ScrollBar to scroll with the TableView.  I've tested this and if the TableView is the primary view for the NavigationController, it shows up fine and scrolls with the Table.  But for some reason, the same setup on a TableView that is then pushed onto the view with the NavigationController doesn't display the SearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set Nib Name property on your Download View Controller under the Tab Bar Controller, in fact that and coupled with setting the class with your class name will automatically create the view for you and you don't have to manually create it.